# ExpressionEngine cannot pull in entries through template

Tags: php, content-management-system, dynamic-data, expressionengine

Hey guys I'm having the damnedest time trying to pull in new entries 
(or ANY entries) through a template and am hoping its something stupid 
I'm missing. I have my content set up in such a way now.

[image: Channels]

Then here's the layout of the blog index, from what I understand this should
show all entries?

```
{exp:channel:entries}
  Show everything?
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

[image: Blog Index]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use the entries tag you also need to supply it a channel to pull data from, see http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/modules/channel/channel_entries.html for the documentation. In order to pull from multiple channels or grab all data you'll need to pipe seperate them on the tag like this

```html
{exp:channel:entries channel="blog|news"}
    Stuff here such as {title}, and {body} depending on how your custom fields are set up
{/exp:channel:entries}
```